# How do I check whether a record has been deleted

Tags: vb.net

I have written a method which deletes a record from the database.

```
Public Overrides Sub Delete(ByVal intDeletingUserID As Integer, Optional ByVal blnLogChanges As Boolean = True)
    If BLMonitor.CountByCustomer(Customer_ID) = 0 And _
        BLComplaint.CountByCustomer(Customer_ID) = 0 And _
        BLRecommendation.CountByCustomer(Customer_ID) = 0 And _
        BLPublicFeedback.CountByCustomer(Customer_ID) = 0 And _
        BLCustomer.CountFeedbackAndReferences(Customer_ID).Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MyBase.Delete(intDeletingUserID, blnLogChanges)
    Else           
End Sub
```

I need to display to the user whether the record can be deleted or not when I implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

If this is winforms application, then you can just use MsgBox or MessageBox.Show to display a message to the user.

For example:

```
Dim sMessage As String
If ...
    MyBase.Delete(intDeletingUserID, blnLogChanges)
    sMessage = "Record Successfully Deleted"
Else  
    sMessage = "Record Cannot Be Deleted"
End If

MsgBox(sMessage)
```

Otherwise, if this is an ASP.Net application, the solution will depend a lot on how you are executing the function (ajax, postback, partial postback, etc).

Assuming that you are doing a full postback, you can use something like:

```
''' <summary>
''' This method generates javascript that will raise an alert on the client side. This 
''' the text that will be displayed to the end user is cleaned of data that will cause 
''' javascript to fail.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sText"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function GenerateAlertJavascript(ByVal sText As String) As String
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sText) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return "alert(""" & sText.Replace(""""c, "").Replace(CRLF, "\n") & """);"
    End If
End Function
```

which can be called in your function like:

```
Dim sMessage As String
If ...
    MyBase.Delete(intDeletingUserID, blnLogChanges)
    sMessage = "Record Successfully Deleted"
Else  
    sMessage = "Record Cannot Be Deleted"
End If

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "AlertScript",  GenerateAlertJavascript(sMessage), True)
```